# How to generate Digital Signature using .PFX file and append it to an existing PDF document using PHP?

Tags: php, digital-signature, tcpdf

I am new to Digital Signature functionality.

I have a .PFX signature file with me. I need to generate digital signature using the file and append it to an existing PDF file.

I have used TCPDF with FPDI to get the content of existing PDF file and append new content to it.

I need the steps on how to generate signature and append it to the existing PDF file.

Also i am facing issue in appending content using FDPI. When trying to append it is overlapping the existing content means it starts appending content from page1. To avoid i need to add a new page to append the content. Is there any possibility to append the signature and some text content at the end of the existing content?

Answer (score 0):

[Is this pdf digital signed correctly? PHP/TCPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209229/is-this-pdf-digital-signed-correctly-php-tcpdf)

Take a look in my solution, I think will resolve your first question.